# Is dynamic typing the same as dynamic(late) binding?

Tags: javascript, types, binding, polymorphism

In late binding the name of a method is bound to a type at runtime. How is this different from dynamic typing?

Comment: Well, certainly not. You try to compare a specific OOP mechanism to bind method names with types at run time with a fundamental strategy to check types in general. However, both techniques have a reduction of type safety in common.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic typing means that you don't have to declare the type of a variable; a variable can hold values of any type, and the type is determined at run time when the variable is used. Most scripting languages use dynamic typing: Javascript, PHP, Python. This contrasts with static typing, which is used in C, C++, and Java.

However, OO languages with static typing do allow a limited form of dynanism, because a class can have subclasses. In Java, a variable declared to hold a class can also hold any of its subclasses; in C++, a pointer to a base class can also point to an object of a derived class.

Late binding refers to how methods of a polymorphic function are selected. If you have a class and a subclass, and bind a method to an an instance of one of these class, does it use the class that performed the binding (which could be the parent class) or the actual class of the object. Early binding means it uses the class that performed the binding, late binding means it uses the actual class of the object. Javascript doesn't actually have classes, so in this case it refers to which prototype in the prototype chain contained the function that performed the method binding.

The two concepts are obviously related. There's no point to late binding if a variable can only hold an object of a single type, so late binding depends on dynamic typing. In C++, you get early binding when you call a member function through an object variable, e.g. `var.func()`. To get late binding, the member function must be declared `virtual` and you have to call it through a pointer, `ptr->func()`. In Java and Javascript, you normally get late binding, but it's possible to use `Function.prototype.bind()` to call the method of a specific prototype.

[Early and Late Binding](http://old.javascript.info/tutorial/binding#early-binding) shows how both early and late binding can be implemented in Javascript prototypes.

EDIT:

Oops, that link no longer works, and it doesn't seem to have gotten archived in the Wayback Machine.. At the moment, the best discussion I can find is at Software Engineering SE: [What is early and late binding?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/200115/what-is-early-and-late-binding)

Comment: This is static and dynamic dispatching. Late binding means that when I call a method on an object the compiler doesn't have any idea whether the method can even be called i.e whether such method exists somewhere. This is postponed to runtime where the name of the method binds to some actual method and then dynamic dispatching is performed, which means the right method implementation is selected based on the type of the actual object. If such function doesn't exist you get a runtime error. So, does dynamic typing imply late binding? Can I have static typing and late binding in the same time?

Comment: I think if you want to get into that level of detail, you shouldbe asking on cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Barmar Your link is broken, that site doesn't exist anymore and is not archived. Can you recommend another resource?

Comment: @ygoe Thanks. I've tried finding another resource, I added a link to softwareengineering.SE.